# Unsecure Images at Checkout

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, checkout, upgrade

After upgrading to Magento 1.7.0.2, two images in the template navigation bar are showing as unsecure at the checkout.

I know the HTTP source but how do I find them in the file manager through Cpanel and how would I go about fixing this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

The images are being listed as insecure because they're being explicitly included into the theme with `http://` - you should resolve this issue in your theme in your theme folder, typically something like:

`/app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/template/page/`

The html should be in there - use file search to find the culprit. If you know the name of the image, search by name.

A best practice is to remove the `http://` designation and use the **protocol agnostic** or **protocol relative** variant. Some more reading:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743247/types-of-urls

http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/